# No view found for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

A number of people have queried on fixing fragments but my confusion may be based on the evolving nature of fragment APIs or I simply misunderstand them.  I am pruning this code to show an attempt to how I am trying to use fragments to have multiple layouts on a big screen or a single layout on a smaller screen that goes to other layouts via buttons.  The essential portion of my log is

```
    12-03 21:17:29.711: E/FragmentManager(13440): No view found for id 0x7f090046     
    (com.ruleagents.rpgsheet:id/main_fragment) for fragment MainFragment{4053b368 #0 ....
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    
    ComponentInfo{com.ruleagents.rpgsheet/com.ruleagents.rpgsheet.SheetActivity}: 
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f090046 
    (com.ruleagents.rpgsheet:id/main_fragment) for fragment MainFragment{4053b368 #0 id=0x7f090046}
    12-03 21:17:29.721: E/AndroidRuntime(13440): at 
    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
```

My activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >    
      <FrameLayout 
       android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.ruleagents.rpgsheet.MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

attribute_fragment.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical" 
         android:id="@+id/linear1">     

    ... nested layout that works independently     

       </LinearLayout>
```

main_fragment.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment" >

          <LinearLayout

        ...
          </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout
        ...
         </LinearLayout>  

         <LinearLayout
         ...      
        </RelativeLayout>
```

With my MainActivity.java as:

```
    package com.ruleagents.rpgsheet;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    ...

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity { //ActionBarActivity {

        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager; // = getFragmentManager();
        AttributeFragment af = new AttributeFragment();
        MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();

        String characterClass, level, att1, att2, att3;
        //other local variables

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment);

            Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

            af.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            mf.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

            if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {  
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment, mf).commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.layout.attribute_fragment, af).commit();
             }else{     
                System.err.println("AAA creating portrait view");
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mf).commit();
             }
        }

        public void onMainButton(View view) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, mf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

        public void onAttributesButton(View view) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.layout.attribute_fragment, af);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        // Unused PlaceholderFragment method ...    
        // unused FragmentPageAdapter ...
        // local methods
    }
```

My MainFragment.java

```
    package com.ruleagents.rpgsheet;

    ... imports

    public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

        public MainFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
        }

    }
```

My SheetActivity.java

```
    package com.ruleagents.rpgsheet;

    ... imports

    public class SheetActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

         // Local variables...

            FragmentManager fragmentManager; // = getFragmentManager();
            AttributeFragment af = new AttributeFragment();
            MainFragment mf = new MainFragment();

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                System.err.println("AAA in onCreate of SheetActivity");
                Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

                //FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                //setContentView(R.layout.whole_sheet);
                System.err.println("AAA got config");

                af.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                mf.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
                fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

                System.err.println("AAA got frag manager");
                if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {  
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mf).commit();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, af).commit();
                 }else{     
                        System.err.println("AAA creating portrait view");
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment, mf).commit();
                 }
            }

            public void onMainButton(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment, mf);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

            public void onSkillsButton(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

            public void onAttributesButton(View view) {
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.layout.attribute_fragment, af);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        // Local methods ...
        // Unused PlaceholderFragment  ...
        // Unused SectionsPagerAdapter 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding a fragment, the add() method needs the container id be in your activity layout that the fragment will go into. So, your error is because there is no main_fragment id in your activity_main.xml.